# Django: Faking a field in the admin interface?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model, `Foo`. It has several database properties, and several properties that are calculated based on a combination of factors. I would like to present these calculated properties to the user as if they were database properties. (The backing factors would be changed to reflect user input.) Is there a way to do this with the Django admin interface?

Comment: Do you want to present them in the admin change list or in the form?

Comment: @lazerscience I'm not sure what the admin change list is. Definitely the form.

Comment: If you want them presented (shown, not editable) in the form, and they're available as methods on the model, then you can just copy the file "change_form.html" to your ${TEMPLATE_ROOT}/admin/APPNAME/MODELNAME/change_form.html and edit it to your heart's content.

Comment: @Elf I do want them to be editable. I want them to act like normal fields, except instead of being saved to a db I get to do processing to update the data accordingly.

Comment: As the Django manual says, "The admin is for trusted users editing structured content.  Full stop."  At this point, you're exceeding the structured content description of the admin, and the recommendation from JKM et. al. is to write your own view that does what you want it to.  You're just torturing yourself trying to "do it the Admin way."  The admin is a nice tool, but it should not be the be-all and end-all of your administrative toolkit.  If you have needs that exceed it, write your own and then hack the admin presentation layer to provide links to it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I would suggest you subclass a modelform for `Foo` (FooAdminForm) to add your own fields not backed by the database. Your custom validation can reside in the `clean_*` methods of ModelForm.

Inside the `save_model` method of `FooAdmin` you get the request, an instance of `Foo` and the form data, so you could do all processing of the data before/after saving the instance.

Here is an example for a model with a custom form registered with django admin:

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin


class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class FooAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # custom field not backed by database
    calculated = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo 


class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # use the custom form instead of a generic modelform
    form = FooAdminForm

    # your own processing
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # for example:
        obj.name = 'Foo #%d' % form.cleaned_data['calculated'] 
        obj.save()


admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

---

**Providing initial values for custom fields based on instance data**

(I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it should work.)

When a modelform for a existing model instance in the database is constructed, it gets passed this instance. So in FooAdminForm's `__init__` one can change the fields attributes based on instance data.

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # only change attributes if an instance is passed            
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        if instance:
            self.fields['calculated'].initial = (instance.bar == 42)
```

Comment: Looks good. However, when I use a `CheckboxInput` instead of `IntegerField`, it doesn't show up. Also, how can I set the initial value of the checkbox? It says that the `check_true` function will be given the "value" of the field, but how do I set what that value is?

Comment: Use a `BooleanField` (it uses CheckboxInput as its default widget). Form fields in django accept a `initial` keyword argument, for example: `bar = forms.BooleanField(initial=True)`

Comment: good to know. How can I set the initial value as a function of the backing model instance?

Comment: @Rosarch I have extended my answer with a possible solution. (I wasn't sure if you get notified about that change, hence the comment)

Comment: +1, Really nice! Only comment: use `super(FooAdminForm, self).__init_(...)` instead of `ModelForm.__init__(self,...)`. Either one works, but `super` is preferred.

Comment: Good lord please don't use `base_fields`.  That's a class attribute!  Instead call `__init__` first (and please use `super`) and then use `self.fields`.

Comment: Also note, that you can override `save` on the model form instead, just call `super` with `commit=False` (which will return the object unsaved), modify your model as appropriate, call `save` on the object, then call `self.save_m2m()` on the form.

Answer (score 7):

It's easy enough to get arbitrary data to show up in change list or make a field show up in the form: `list_display` arbitrarily takes either actual model properties, or methods defined on the model or the modeladmin, and you can subclass `forms.ModelForm` to add any field type you'd like to the change form.

What's far more difficult/impossible is combining the two, i.e. having an arbitrary piece of data on the change list that you can edit in-place by specifying `list_editable`. Django seems to only accept a true model property that corresponds to a database field. (even using `@property` on the method in the model definition is not enough).

Has anyone found a way to edit a field not actually present on the model right from the change list page?

Comment: i would love to get the answer for that

Answer (score 1):

In the edit form, put the property name into [readonly_fields](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) (1.2 upwards only).

In the changelist, put it into [list_display](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).

Comment: But I do want the property to be editable - it just doesn't correspond directly to a database row, I need to do my own processing to change the backend data accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @property decorator in your model (Python >= 2.4):

```
class Product(models.Model):

    @property
    def ranking(self):
        return 1
```

"ranking" can then be used in `list_display`:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('ranking', 'asin', 'title')
```

Comment: `@property` is not required. `list_display` will accept any method on the model (or ModelAdmin)