# How to add a custom field in django model form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to add a readonly field in a form.

The model `Folder` is registered in admin site. The `FolderAdminForm` defines the custom field `statistics`. There isn't `statistcs` field in the `Folder` model, I just want to put some readonly data on the form. This data is defined in the template.

But I get a error whenever the user doesn't have edit permission. If the user only have the view permission,this error is raised:

```
AttributeError: Unable to lookup 'statistics' on Folder or FolderAdmin
```

Here is my code:

```
class CustomWidget(forms.Textarea):
    template_name = 'widget.html'


class FolderAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Folder
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3',)

    statistics = forms.Field(
        widget=CustomWidget,
        label='Estatísticas',
        help_text='Estatísticas da pasta',
    )
```

Comment: Please post your `FolderAdmin` class.

Answer (score 4):

According to the last part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4893172/9225671), you could try to override the forms `__init__()` method and assign the fields `initial` attribute.

This could look like:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # only change attributes if an instance is passed            
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        if instance:
            self.base_fields['statistics'].initial = 'something'
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

The error only occurred whenever I tried to open a folder instance without edit permission (i.e. with read only permission). Therefore, django consider the statistics field as a read only field and then search for a label for this field. Django look for this label in Model, ModelAdmin. Since none of them has the 'statistics' attribute, the error is raised. 
So, this worked for me:

```
 class FolderAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Folder
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3',)

        labels = {'statistics': 'Estatísticas'}

    statistics = forms.Field(
        widget=CustomWidget,
        label='Estatísticas',
        help_text='Estatísticas da pasta',
    )
```

Therefore, whenever django looks for a label for statistics, it finds this label and the error is not raised. I don't know why it doesn't recognize the label passed as a Field parameter.